# Unable to deploy java ee7-tutorial examples JDeveloper to Glassfish

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, glassfish, jdeveloper

I am experiencing issues while deploying java ee7-tutorial examples from JDeveloper to Glassfish 4 server.

I downloaded the samples from http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/usingexamples001.htm#GEXBA

**NOTE** I can successfully build and deploy the tutorial examples using Netbeans and GlassFish. All the samples works fine.

Some samples don't run fine when deployed from JDeveloper to GlassFish. I used Maven to build the sample projects. I compared the war files built from Netbeans 7.4 with JDeveloper 12C, I found that the below files differences between the wars deployed from different IDEs.

- META-INF (folder) : Missing from JDeveloper deployed WAR
- resource bundles (.properties files) : Resource and xhtml in multiple places

Here is screenshot of war file diff. Left side one is generated using Netbeans where as right side one is generated from JDeveloper.

[image: screenshot of war diff]

compare classes of war generated from netbeans vs jdeveloper. [image: compare classes of war generated from netbeans vs jdeveloper]

As you see, resource bundle files are missing from the left hand side (which is a war deployed from JDeveloper to Glassfish) and also noticed that xhtml (files in contact, index and template) and resources are copied to classes instead.

Am I missing any configuration when deploying from JDeveloper to Glassfish?

Comment: Figured it out. The project had multiple issues. Added resources folder to project source in JDeveloper, updated pom file to generate the required persistence, updated persistence.xml with the missing ORM provider info.                                            HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The project had multiple issues. Added resources folder to project source in JDeveloper, updated pom file to generate the required persistence, updated persistence.xml with the missing ORM provider info. HTH!